# HTML editor that detects errors in code

Tags: android, html-editor

On my PC, I use [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/) to edit HTML code. It has code highlighting and is also able to detect possible errors in the code. For example, improper nesting of tags.

I need a similar software for my Android 4.2. I currently use [WebMaster's HTML Editor Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO&hl=en) but it cannot detect errors in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a similar app: [AWD](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.kidinov.awd). From its description:

> **Main Features:**
>
> - Support all major web languages and formats: PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML
> - A lot of ways to reach your project ( FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WEBDav and growing)
> - Integration with web server
> - Code highlighting
> - Autodetection of file's encoding
> - Code completion
> - **Error checking**
> - Hardware keyboard support (e.g hotkeys)
> - Code beautifying with one click
> - Tablet ready UI
> - Line numbering
> - Quick preview of your page
> - Highlighting the current line
> - Search and replace with regular expressions
> - Unlimited Undo/redo
> - Full screen mode
> - Recent projects
> - Periodical autosaving
> - Git integration
> - Rename/create/delete/copy-paste files inside you project

As you see, error checking is one of its *highlighted* features (the emphasis is taken from the original description). Seems like it's exactly what you're looking for. Comes for free, and is well rated (currently 4.6 with almost 500 votes).